# Floating icon on other applications

Tags: android-layout, android

I am curious to know how [emojidom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plantpurple.emojidom) is able to show this icon on top of other applications. What it actually is? Because this icon pops up on  whatsapp, hangouts, facebook messenger and other chatting applications. And also I can move this icon all around the screen. How is it doing so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They may be using

> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
>   [refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at source of HALO implemented by ParanoidAndroid

https://github.com/ParanoidAndroid/HALO